# Start Debugging command launches silverlight html page via file system rather than in local web server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight 4 project in VS2010 along with a web project to host the silverlight app. When I hit F5 to launch the debugger the auto-generated html page (SilverlightApplication2TestPage.html) launches in IE, but the page is loaded via the file system (C:\Users\Chloraphil\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2\Bin\Debug\SilverlightApplication2TestPage.html).

I want the aspx page to launch via the embedded web server. I have right clicked the aspx file and selected "Set as Start Page" and confirmed it is set in the "Web" tab in the properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `SilverlightApplication2.Web` project (the one that contains the .aspx page) as StartUp project (**Set as StartUp project** in context menu in Solution Explorer).